# removing object property with highest value and put results in a array

Tags: javascript

Here is my object:

```
 let obj = {0: 1, 1: 10, 2: 100, 3: 10}
```

Based on `obj` property values how can we fill an array (`let arr`) with obj properties except for property with a maximum value like:

```
arr = [0,1,3]
```

the property named 2 has maximum value so we removed it from `arr`

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried to do to solve it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the values and the maximum and filter the keys.

```js
var object = { 0: 1, 1: 10, 2: 100, 3: 10 },
    max = Math.max(...Object.values(object)),
    result = Object
        .keys(object)
        .filter(k => object[k] !== max)
        .map(Number);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using an object if you're just giving it consecutive numerical keys? That's re-creating arrays. Just use an array to begin with, calculate its maximum value, then filter those entries out:

```
let obj = [1, 10, 100, 10];
const indexes = obj.map((val, i) => i);
const maximum = Math.max(...obj);
let arr = indexes.filter(i => obj[i] !== maximum);
```

**EDIT** If it MUST be an object, so you can use non-consecutive keys for some reason, just change where you get the data from:

```
let obj = {0: 1, 1: 10, 2: 100, 3: 10};
const indexes = Object.keys(obj);
const maximum = Math.max(...(Object.values(obj));
let arr = indexes.filter(i => obj[i] !== maximum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if I had  `let obj = {2: 1, 44: 10, 24: 100, 4: 10}`

Comment: Updated my answer.